# ssh public key login failed randomly to my ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I have a ubuntu server,which is within a local network of a company, and we made a ip mapping so that we can access that computer from WAN.
I 've generated a pub key and add to authorized_keys as well.

the first couple of times of login was successful, but later I ssh the server it will pop up to let me fill the password. I mean it's random to log in without password which it should supposed to be always log in using puk key.

here is the permission setting of the ssh dir on server

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 fin fin 4096 2011-10-19 11:47 .ssh
drwxrwxr-x  2 fin fin 4096 2011-10-19 11:47 .
drwx------ 11 fin fin 4096 2011-11-30 11:10 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 fin fin  804 2011-11-29 20:06 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 fin fin 1675 2011-10-19 11:46 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 fin fin  403 2011-10-19 11:46 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 fin fin  884 2011-10-19 11:47 known_hosts
```

here is the verbose connect info

```
openSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 211.154.169.179 [211.154.169.179] port 1066.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/lidongbin/.ssh/identity type -1
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug1: identity file /Users/lidongbin/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/lidongbin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 124/256
debug2: bits set: 525/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '[211.154.169.179]:1066' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/lidongbin/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug2: bits set: 517/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/lidongbin/.ssh/identity (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/lidongbin/.ssh/id_rsa (0x100118e10)
debug2: key: /Users/lidongbin/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/lidongbin/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/lidongbin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/lidongbin/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

here is the /var/log/auth.log

```
Nov 30 11:11:35 vrv-oes sshd[30474]: Connection from 192.168.0.1 port 55669
Nov 30 11:11:41 vrv-oes sshd[30474]: Failed publickey for fin from 192.168.0.1 port 55669 ssh2
Nov 30 11:11:46 vrv-oes sshd[30529]: pam_ecryptfs: Passphrase file wrapped
Nov 30 11:11:47 vrv-oes sshd[30474]: Accepted password for fin from 192.168.0.1 port 55669 ssh2
Nov 30 11:11:47 vrv-oes sshd[30474]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user fin by (uid=0)
Nov 30 11:11:47 vrv-oes sshd[30474]: User child is on pid 30561
```

have you ever encounter this problem? 
I am so confused about this for days...

anyone can help me? thanks for advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you increase the verbosity of the sshd server it may give you more information as to why the key was not accepted.  The times that I have run into issues, is either a time server issue (where it was setting the clock to weird values) or permission problems -- sshd wants it's configuration files with a specific permission.

Comment: thanks awrn, I add the verbose to the ssh server config, but when i check the /var/log/auth.log it only tell me this "Failed publickey for fin from 192.168.0.1 port 55669 ssh2" , no more infos? should i find the specific log elsewhere? thanks

Comment: and my server's .ssh dir permission is "drwxrwxr-x  2 fin  fin    4096 2011-10-19 11:47 .ssh" , I think it is enough.

Comment: Start a new sshd in debug to see what's going on: # /usr/sbin/sshd -D -ddd -p 60022  --- now start a new ssh from the client to port 60222 and you should see sshd's debug right on screen as it's happening.  It should be a lot more information there.

Comment: it's not only the server ssh directory, it's the users sshd directory as well.  There may also be user restrictions specially for 'root'.  So do your testing using an account other than root.

Comment: Sorry guys,it seems the setting of wan LAN mapping's wrong config.